# Detect audio playing with pycaw, ctypes, and comtypes: Fails

Tags: python, windows, ctypes

I'm trying to detect whether audio is playing on a Windows 11 machine, python 3.11.3. The program runs correctly for a few iterations, but then fails silently.

I need help debugging this program so that I can make it work reliably for extended periods (days).

I put in the initialization and uninitialization functions hoping that that might fix the problem. It had no effect. The program behaves the same with or without those functions.

```
import time
import logging

from pycaw.pycaw import AudioUtilities, IAudioSessionControl2
from comtypes import POINTER, CoInitialize, CoUninitialize
from ctypes import cast

# Setup logging
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG, format='%(asctime)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s')

# Define the AudioSessionState enumeration
class AudioSessionState:
    AudioSessionStateInactive = 0
    AudioSessionStateActive = 1
    AudioSessionStateExpired = 2

def is_audio_playing():
    CoInitialize()
    try:
        sessions = AudioUtilities.GetAllSessions()
        for session in sessions:
            try:
                audio_control = cast(session._ctl, POINTER(IAudioSessionControl2))
                state = audio_control.GetState()
                if state == AudioSessionState.AudioSessionStateActive:
                    return True
            except Exception as e:
                logging.error(f"Exception: {e}")
                raise e
    except Exception as e:
        logging.critical(f"Critical error in is_audio_playing: {e}")
        raise e
    finally:
        CoUninitialize()
    return False

iteration = 0
while True:
    try:
        iteration += 1
        logging.info(f"Iteration {iteration}: {is_audio_playing()}")
        time.sleep(1)
    except Exception as e:
        logging.error(f"Exception: {e}")
        raise e
```

It leaves the following event report in the Event Viewer each time it fails.

```
- System 

  - Provider 

   [ Name]  Application Error 
   [ Guid]  {a0e9b465-b939-57d7-b27d-95d8e925ff57} 
 
   EventID 1000 
 
   Version 0 
 
   Level 2 
 
   Task 100 
 
   Opcode 0 
 
   Keywords 0x8000000000000000 
 
  - TimeCreated 

   [ SystemTime]  2023-12-13T00:25:26.3818329Z 
 
   EventRecordID 26243 
 
   Correlation 
 
  - Execution 

   [ ProcessID]  32952 
   [ ThreadID]  11272 
 
   Channel Application 
 
   Computer Ikon 
 
  - Security 

   [ UserID]  S-1-5-21-3641799435-1895349376-3777817403-1001 
 

- EventData 

  AppName python.exe 
  AppVersion 3.11.3150.1013 
  AppTimeStamp 642cb853 
  ModuleName _ctypes.pyd 
  ModuleVersion 3.11.3150.1013 
  ModuleTimeStamp 642cb828 
  ExceptionCode c0000005 
  FaultingOffset 00000000000074b1 
  ProcessId 0x5eb4 
  ProcessCreationTime 0x1da2d5ab79efffc 
  AppPath C:\Python311\python.exe 
  ModulePath C:\Python311\DLLs\_ctypes.pyd 
  IntegratorReportId a15a3e44-164e-4d8e-a0fa-bdb530c0771e 
  PackageFullName  
  PackageRelativeAppId
```

I expected the program would continue to run until I canceled it, printing true or false every second depending on whether audio is playing or not. It correctly prints true or false while it is running, but it always fails silently (without printing error messages) within a minute or two. I have tried running it in debug mode with the same result. Interestingly, with logging level set to DEBUG, it prints the following, with varying values for ptr, for each iteration. In this case, it failed during iteration 26.

```
2023-12-12 19:42:37,098 - DEBUG - CoInitializeEx(None, 2)
2023-12-12 19:42:37,104 - DEBUG - Release <POINTER(IMMDeviceEnumerator) ptr=0x22630b64a90 at 22630a26950>
2023-12-12 19:42:37,106 - DEBUG - Release <POINTER(IMMDevice) ptr=0x226301d77d0 at 22632a9bbd0>
2023-12-12 19:42:37,106 - DEBUG - Release <POINTER(IUnknown) ptr=0x22630af5f00 at 22630a26950>
2023-12-12 19:42:37,107 - DEBUG - Release <POINTER(IAudioSessionControl) ptr=0x22630af3830 at 22632a9bbd0>
2023-12-12 19:42:37,107 - DEBUG - Release <POINTER(IAudioSessionManager2) ptr=0x22630af5f00 at 22632a9acd0>
2023-12-12 19:42:37,107 - DEBUG - Release <POINTER(IAudioSessionEnumerator) ptr=0x22632ce8040 at 22630a26950>
2023-12-12 19:42:37,107 - DEBUG - Release <POINTER(IAudioSessionControl) ptr=0x22632cfc620 at 22632a9bcd0>
2023-12-12 19:42:37,108 - DEBUG - Release <POINTER(IAudioSessionControl2) ptr=0x22630af3838 at 22630a26950>
2023-12-12 19:42:37,108 - DEBUG - CoUninitialize()
2023-12-12 19:42:37,108 - DEBUG - Release <POINTER(IAudioSessionControl2) ptr=0x22632cfc628 at 22632a9bcd0>
2023-12-12 19:42:37,109 - INFO - Iteration 25: False
2023-12-12 19:42:38,109 - DEBUG - CoInitializeEx(None, 2)
2023-12-12 19:42:38,119 - DEBUG - Release <POINTER(IMMDeviceEnumerator) ptr=0x22630b64a90 at 22630a26950>
2023-12-12 19:42:38,119 - DEBUG - Release <POINTER(IMMDevice) ptr=0x22630af48d0 at 22632a9bcd0>
2023-12-12 19:42:38,119 - DEBUG - Release <POINTER(IUnknown) ptr=0x22630af5f00 at 22630a26950>
2023-12-12 19:42:38,120 - DEBUG - Release <POINTER(IAudioSessionControl2) ptr=0x22630af39a8 at 22632a9a450>
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Why calling *COM* (un)initialization functions inside yours and not only once (before / after the main loop)? also are you sure that objects that one other package works with are compatible with another?

Comment: I put in the initialization and uninitialization functions hoping that that might fix the problem. It had no effect. The program behaves the same with or without those functions. 
I am not sure which objects and packages are referring to. Do you have any suggestions for how to fix the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out to be simple. This code does exactly what I want.

```
import time
from pycaw.pycaw import AudioUtilities

def is_audio_playing():
    sessions = AudioUtilities.GetAllSessions()
    for session in sessions:
        if session.State == 1:  # State == 1 means the audio session is active
            return True
    return False

while True:
    if is_audio_playing():
        print("Audio is currently playing.")
    else:
        print("No audio is playing.")
    time.sleep(1)
```